# Cannot parse JSON data from Socket.IO using JSONJoy

Tags: ios, json, node.js, swift, socket.io

I am trying to convert JSON received from Socket.IO using JSONJoy. I have the following struct for the JSONJoy protocol

```
struct Order: JSONJoy {
    let location: String?
    let username: String?

    init(_ decoder: JSONDecoder) {
        location = decoder["location"].string
        username = decoder["username"].string
    }
  }
```

I have set my Socket up like so

```
socket.on("order") {data, ack in
    let order = Order(JSONDecoder(data))
    print(order)
}
```

The response is always

```
Order(location: nil, username: nil)
```

The orders are emitted like so

```
var order = JSON.stringify("{ 'username': 'Test', 'location': 'Start'}");
localSocket.emit('order', order);
```

I am able to confirm connection on both the iOS and server endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `JSON.stringify`on a string. Either just emit the string, or stringify an object.

e.g.

```
var order = JSON.stringify({username: 'Test', location: 'Start'});
```